# How to limit the Mongodb Index size

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongodb 3.2.1  with Wired Tiger engine.Currently my one of the collection index size was 29879107584 and I am having 30GB of RAM in the Ubuntu 14.04 system.Is there any configuration where I can set the collection to use the limited index size instead of above.In this case will it affect the insertion for new documents. Below is the collection stats and sample document.

```
{
        "ns" : "XXX.AAA",
        "count" : 749609911,
        "size" : 140729861965,
        "avgObjSize" : 187,
        "storageSize" : 37054742528,
        "capped" : false,
        "wiredTiger" : {
                "metadata" : {
                        "formatVersion" : 1
                },
                "creationString" : "allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1),block_allocation=best,block_compressor=snappy,cache_resident=0,checksum=on,colgroups=,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,encryption=(keyid=,name=),exclusive=0,extractor=,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,immutable=0,internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=,internal_page_max=4KB,key_format=q,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=32KB,leaf_value_max=64MB,log=(enabled=),lsm=(auto_throttle=,bloom=,bloom_bit_count=16,bloom_config=,bloom_hash_count=8,bloom_oldest=0,chunk_count_limit=0,chunk_max=5GB,chunk_size=10MB,merge_max=15,merge_min=0),memory_page_max=10m,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,prefix_compression=0,prefix_compression_min=4,source=,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,type=file,value_format=u",
                "type" : "file",
                "uri" : "statistics:table:collection-11-7249043912214591751",
                "LSM" : {
                        "bloom filters in the LSM tree" : 0,
                        "bloom filter false positives" : 0,
                        "bloom filter hits" : 0,
                        "bloom filter misses" : 0,
                        "bloom filter pages evicted from cache" : 0,
                        "bloom filter pages read into cache" : 0,
                        "total size of bloom filters" : 0,
                        "sleep for LSM checkpoint throttle" : 0,
                        "chunks in the LSM tree" : 0,
                        "highest merge generation in the LSM tree" : 0,
                        "queries that could have benefited from a Bloom filter that did not exist" : 0,
                        "sleep for LSM merge throttle" : 0
                },
                "block-manager" : {
                        "file allocation unit size" : 4096,
                        "blocks allocated" : 2056317,
                        "checkpoint size" : 37069619200,
                        "allocations requiring file extension" : 2041522,
                        "blocks freed" : 16252,
                        "file magic number" : 120897,
                        "file major version number" : 1,
                        "minor version number" : 0,
                        "file bytes available for reuse" : 53248,
                        "file size in bytes" : 37054742528
                },
                "btree" : {
                        "btree checkpoint generation" : 42209,
                        "column-store variable-size deleted values" : 0,
                        "column-store fixed-size leaf pages" : 0,
                        "column-store internal pages" : 0,
                        "column-store variable-size RLE encoded values" : 0,
                        "column-store variable-size leaf pages" : 0,
                        "pages rewritten by compaction" : 0,
                        "number of key/value pairs" : 0,
                        "fixed-record size" : 0,
                        "maximum tree depth" : 5,
                        "maximum internal page key size" : 368,
                        "maximum internal page size" : 4096,
                        "maximum leaf page key size" : 3276,
                        "maximum leaf page size" : 32768,
                        "maximum leaf page value size" : 67108864,
                        "overflow pages" : 0,
                        "row-store internal pages" : 0,
                        "row-store leaf pages" : 0
                },
                "cache" : {
                        "bytes read into cache" : 795145173593,
                        "bytes written from cache" : 66009307193,
                        "checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 0,
                        "unmodified pages evicted" : 24432718,
                        "page split during eviction deepened the tree" : 0,
                        "modified pages evicted" : 28826,
                        "data source pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted" : 100549,
                        "hazard pointer blocked page eviction" : 55965,
                        "internal pages evicted" : 235292,
                        "internal pages split during eviction" : 150,
                        "leaf pages split during eviction" : 12518,
                        "in-memory page splits" : 9408,
                        "in-memory page passed criteria to be split" : 18910,
                        "overflow values cached in memory" : 0,
                        "pages read into cache" : 24602873,
                        "pages read into cache requiring lookaside entries" : 0,
                        "overflow pages read into cache" : 0,
                        "pages written from cache" : 2053921,
                        "page written requiring lookaside records" : 0,
                        "pages written requiring in-memory restoration" : 0
                },
                "compression" : {
                        "raw compression call failed, no additional data available" : 0,
                        "raw compression call failed, additional data available" : 0,
                        "raw compression call succeeded" : 0,
                        "compressed pages read" : 24372175,
                        "compressed pages written" : 2023673,
                        "page written failed to compress" : 0,
                        "page written was too small to compress" : 30248
                },
                "cursor" : {
                        "create calls" : 1288,
                        "insert calls" : 332854777,
                        "bulk-loaded cursor-insert calls" : 0,
                        "cursor-insert key and value bytes inserted" : 64441812745,
                        "next calls" : 1531315547,
                        "prev calls" : 1,
                        "remove calls" : 426721,
                        "cursor-remove key bytes removed" : 2133605,
                        "reset calls" : 411834660,
                        "restarted searches" : 10489,
                        "search calls" : 3004784718,
                        "search near calls" : 12020300,
                        "truncate calls" : 0,
                        "update calls" : 0,
                        "cursor-update value bytes updated" : 0
                },
                "reconciliation" : {
                        "dictionary matches" : 0,
                        "internal page multi-block writes" : 1385,
                        "leaf page multi-block writes" : 12742,
                        "maximum blocks required for a page" : 20,
                        "internal-page overflow keys" : 0,
                        "leaf-page overflow keys" : 0,
                        "overflow values written" : 0,
                        "pages deleted" : 2669,
                        "fast-path pages deleted" : 0,
                        "page checksum matches" : 58274,
                        "page reconciliation calls" : 33906,
                        "page reconciliation calls for eviction" : 16209,
                        "leaf page key bytes discarded using prefix compression" : 0,
                        "internal page key bytes discarded using suffix compression" : 2069008
                },
                "session" : {
                        "object compaction" : 0,
                        "open cursor count" : 4
                },
                "transaction" : {
                        "update conflicts" : 0
                }
        },
        "nindexes" : 4,
        "totalIndexSize" : 30414229504,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 7513280512,
                "bookid_1_sheetname_1_top_1_bottom_1_column_1" : 6909124608,
                "bookid_1_sheetname_1_row_1_column_1" : 7578796032,
                "bookid_1_sheetname_1_row_1_column_1_value_1" : 8413028352
        },
        "ok" : 1
}



{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54fdf0540cf26047a823e123"),
        "height" : 15,
        "sheetname" : "Test Sheet",
        "width" : 225,
        "value" : "Test",
        "bottom" : 14,
        "column" : 1,
        "left" : 0,
        "right" : 224,
        "row" : 1,
        "top" : 0,
        "bookid" : ObjectId("54fdf0537a0a58734f11aa17")
}
```

Comment: Post your db.collection.stats and also your sample document.